# SQL Server equivalent of Excel's TINV function

Tags: sql, sql-server, distribution, probability

I am trying to find two-tailed inverse of the X's t-distribution. It can be find using TINV function in Excel but I need this to achieve in SQL Sever. Please suggest me idea.

The TINV function syntax has the following arguments:

**Probability** : The probability associated with the two-tailed Student's t-distribution.

**Deg_freedom** : The number of degrees of freedom with which to characterize the distribution.

Ex:

```
select tinv( 0.054645, 60);
-- -----------------
--  1.9599994129833
--  (1 row returned)
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server supports such functions natively.  There may be statistical packages that you can add in with this support.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you please explain what is statistical packages?

Comment: This might help: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=138441

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL-Server does not incorporate  a lot of statistical functions. 
`tinv` is not present in SQL-Server.

The only way to add a tinv function, is to use a CLR-Function. 
Thus, the problem reduces itselfs to "How do I calculate tinv with the subset of C# allowed in SQL-Server ?".

If you're on .NET 4.0, you could use the chart-class in `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`

e.g.

```
var someChart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
double res = someChart.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseTDistribution(.05, 15);

//2.131449546
```

However, you probably don't want that overhead. 
So you'll have to rip it out of [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/StudentT.htm)'s SourceCode (MIT/X11 License).

```
StudentT dist = new StudentT(0.0,1.0,7.0);          
double prob = dist.CumulativeDistribution(1.8946);
```

Which should result in 0.95

Since you need the inverse, you'll need

```
StudentT.InvCDF(double location, double scale, double freedom, double p)
```

location: The location (μ) of the distribution. 
scale: The scale (σ) of the distribution. Range: σ > 0. 
freedom: The degrees of freedom (ν) for the distribution. Range: ν > 0.
p: The location at which to compute the inverse cumulative density.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble TInv(double probability, int degFreedom)
{  
    double result = 0.00; 
    try
    {
        result = fnInverseTDistribution(degFreedom, probability);
    }
    catch
    {
        // throw; // Optionally throw/log/ignore/whatever
    }
    return result;
}
```

using DataVisualization, this goes like this:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble TInv(double probability, int degFreedom)
{  
    double result = 0.00; 
    try
    {

        var someChart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
        result  = someChart.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseTDistribution( probability, degFreedom);
    }
    catch
    {
        // throw; // Optionally throw/log/ignore/whatever
    }
    return result;
}
```

The DataVisualization trick however won't work on SQL-Server, because you'd need to add a reference to System.Web, which you can't do in SQL-Server.

Also, excel has a lot of similar functions, tinv, t.inv, T.INV.2S, etc., so be sure to choose the right one.

## Edit:

Found some more information:
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/ExcelFunctions.htm#TIn

There is a special class called ExcelFunctions in Math.NET that you can actually use:

```
MathNet.Numerics.ExcelFunctions.TInv (1.1, 55);
```

You find some more information on [TINV](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TINV_function) and [TDIST](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TDIST_function) on OpenOffice.org along with a list of functions by [by category](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Functions_listed_by_category)

So the solution to your problem is

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble TInv(double probability, int degFreedom)
{  
    double result = 0.00; 
    try
    {
        result  = MathNet.Numerics.ExcelFunctions.TInv (probability, degFreedom);
    }
    catch
    {
        // throw; // Optionally throw/log/ignore/whatever
    }
    return result;
}
```

which is actually the same as

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble TInv(double probability, int degFreedom)
{  
    double result = 0.00; 
    try
    {
        result  = -StudentT.InvCDF(0d, 1d, degFreedom, probability/2);
    }
    catch
    {
        // throw; // Optionally throw/log/ignore/whatever
    }
    return result;
}
```

So now you grab the sourcecode of Math.Net from 
https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics
and drag and drop the contents of mathnet-numerics/src/Numerics/ (or the part thereof that you need) into your project with the CRL-Function, and finished.

When you have your CLR dll, you go into SSMS and execute:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_configure 'clr enabled',1 RECONFIGURE WITH

CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLServerStatistics from 'C:\SQLServerStatistics.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

After that has succeeded, you still have to register the function with SQL-Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tinv](@prob float, @degFreedom int)
    RETURNS float WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SQLServerStatistics].[Functions].[TInv]
```

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37377/SQL-Server-CLR-Functions) article for further information.

If you want to bring the Dll onto a productive server, you'll need to create the assembly from a byte-array-string, like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyFunctions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A90000[very long string here...];
```

You create the hex string from the byte array like this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\SQLServerStatistics.dll");
"0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "")
```

I have uploaded the entire solution [here](https://github.com/ststeiger/SqlServerStatistics) on github.

Then you can run the function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.tinv(0.54645, 60)
```

==> 0.606531559343638

The Script-Generator tool automatically builds the install script for you. 
Looks like this:

```
> sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; GO RECONFIGURE; GO
> sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1; GO RECONFIGURE; GO
> 
> 
> DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)  SET @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE ' +
> QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + ' SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;' 
> -- PRINT @sql; EXECUTE(@sql); GO
> 
> 
> -- Restore sid when db restored from backup... DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<<DatabaseName>> TO
> [<<LoginName>>]'  SELECT @Command = REPLACE (     REPLACE(@Command,
> N'<<DatabaseName>>', SD.Name)     , N'<<LoginName>>'  , SL.Name ) FROM
> master..sysdatabases AS SD  JOIN master..syslogins AS SL      ON  SD.SID
> = SL.SID 
> 
> WHERE SD.Name = DB_NAME()
> 
> -- PRINT @command  EXECUTE(@command)  GO
> 
>           IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TDist]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS',
> N'FT')) DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TDist] GO
>     
>           IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TInv]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS',
> N'FT')) DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TInv] GO
>     
> 
> 
> IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name =
> N'SQLServerStatistics' and is_user_defined = 1) DROP ASSEMBLY
> [SQLServerStatistics] GO
> 
> 
> CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLServerStatistics AUTHORIZATION [dbo] 
>     FROM 'c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SqlServerStatistics\ClrCreationScriptGenerator\bin\Debug\SqlServerStatistics.dll'
> WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE GO
> 
> 
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TDist](@x AS float, @degFreedom AS int, @tails
> AS int)
>     RETURNS float WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME [SQLServerStatistics].[SqlServerStatistics.ExcelFunctions].[TDist] GO
> 
> 
> 
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TInv](@probability AS float, @degFreedom AS
> int)
>     RETURNS float WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME [SQLServerStatistics].[SqlServerStatistics.ExcelFunctions].[TInv] GO
```

Comment: Oh, and Math.NET requires .NET 4 (or 3.5). So you need SQL-Server 2012 or 2014, otherwise you need to change the default CLR for SQL-Server 2008 R1 & R2

Answer (score 2):

You could either write your own implementation as a SQL function or use a [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write it in C#.

My advice would be to use a CLR and include the [Accord](http://accord-framework.net) library (I recommend this one because they still have .NET 3.5 versions which you will need for a SQL Server CLR) to implement the statistic function. I've done this for other statistic calculations in the past and it worked like a charme.

Comment: Actually, 3.5 is worthless, you need either 2.0 ( for SQL-Server 2008 R1 & R2) or 4.0, for SQL-Server 2012 and 2014.

Comment: No you are wrong...the CLR version is 2.0 but the actual .NET runtime can be 3.5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430/what-version-of-net-framework-ships-with-sql-server-2008

Comment: Mmmmh, possible, but wonder what happens when you call a function or use a type that's only in the 3.5 class libraries.

Comment: I've used this for the past 3 years in different CLRs and never had a problem, but I have to admit I never spend any attention if I've used only 2.0 functions. But that said, it still worked for me flawlessly with Accord (and also old Math.NET 3.5 buids)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the qt function in R. Here is a code snip:

```
DECLARE @confinPerc float, @setCount integer
SET @confinPerc = .95
SET @setCount = 5
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #R_RES;
CREATE TABLE #R_RES(res float);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(100)
SET @sql =N'SELECT ' + CAST(1-@confinPerc AS NVARCHAR) + ' AS prob, ' + CAST(@setCount - 2 AS NVARCHAR) + ' AS dF;'
INSERT INTO #R_RES
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
   ,@script = N' res <- qt(1-InputDataSet$prob/2,InputDataSet$dF);
       df <- data.frame(res);'
       ,@input_data_1 = @sql
   ,@output_data_1_name = N'df';

SELECT * FROM #R_RES;
```